# Is it possible to create subdomain for separate Site in the same IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-express, asp.net-4.5

I have two separate sites.
for one I have domain and the other not.
I want to add the site to the server IIS and give it some subdomain name.
Is it possible ?

Can I create subdomain for separate site in the same IIS?
if the answer is yes what is the best way to do it ?
I am working with IIS-7
Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069278/how-to-set-up-subdomains-on-iis-7