# How to create an alias of my web application for each user?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, web-hosting

I need to create something like: **http://username.mydomain.com**.

I´m using **ASP.NET** and my web application will be hosted in a **IIS Server**.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069278/how-to-set-up-subdomains-on-iis-7) I must add an additional website in IIS named **username.mydomain.com**. Does it mean that if I have one million users I have to create one million of additional website?

I don´t think this is the best solution.

Comment: Is it 100% necessary to create username.mydomain.com? Can't you get away instead with doing mydomain.com/username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate website for each additional account - [you just need a new HTTP Host header binding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx). You can do this either by creating a new binding for each additional subdomain, or use a "catchall" (default) binding that handles all requests for a given port binding. IIS 10.0 (Windows Server 2016) finally added support for "wildcard" host-headers so that's now the preferred option for this scenario: https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support