# Create a subdomain and point it to domain location

Tags: asp.net, iis, subdomain

So I have a follow up question based on [How To Setup Subdomains on iis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069278/how-to-set-up-subdomains-on-iis-7)

I am using IIS 8, and I am looking to point my subdomain to my current default website. Currently we have `www.mydomain.com`, and I setup a subdomain in our DNS A Record that is `account.mydomain.com` pointing to the same IP address of `mydomain.com`.

I figured the way to create the subdomain is now to go to Site Bindings under the Default Website in IIS and add a site binding with the hostname `account.mydomain.com` but I am getting an error that says the server IP address cannot be found. The reason I didn't want to create a new Site in IIS is because we have certain properties and permissions that are setup.

Eventually we will be changing the IP Address of `www.mydomain.com` to be pointing to something new, but for the time being we need `account.mydomain.com` to point to the same location as `www.mydomain.com`

Images for reference -
[image]
[image]

Comment: `account.mydomain.com` and `www.account.mydomain.com` are different domains if you didn't know.

Comment: @LexLi yes, sorry didn't mean the confusion. It should be `account.mydomain.com`

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot to explain "I am getting an error that says the server IP address cannot be found"?

Comment: @LexLi updated the question for you

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your machine's DNS configuration (where you took the screen shot), as I can even now access that site via `account.xxx.com`.

Comment: @LexLi not sure I follow - can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: As I can access that site over the internet, your settings on IIS side are correct. About why your own machine and the browser cannot open it, that's a networking issue (DNS related), which you should talk to your network administrators.

Comment: @LexLi oh, so settings are correct, and you are able to go to `account.metsales.com` and it is the same as `metsales.com`? Also I am the network admin >.<

Comment: If you are the network admin you forgot a few things: 1) test on multiple machines (internal/external). 2) Commands like `nslookup` or tools like Wireshark are commonly used when the browser says it cannot access the domain, so that you can look into DNS packets. Again, it is no longer programming related, off-topic here.