# Redirect to https works partially asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dns

I have setup my project to always redirect to `https` and it works when users type `http://website.com or website.com` but it doesn't work when he type `http://www.website.com or https://www.website.com or www.website.com`

This is setup i have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

and inside `Configure` i do have `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

Project is developed in `.NET Core 2.1`

after some time i came back to this problem since it is not solved yet with any of bellow answers.

Here is full code of my startup - it is messed up since i tried a lot of stuff and to be fair i am lost now...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Termodom.Models;

namespace Termodom
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public static string Version = "v1.2.0.0";



        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Initialize();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            AR.AR.ConnectionString = Program.ConnectionString;
            AR.ARWebAuthorization.ARWebAuthorization.AutoUserTimeout = true;
            AR.TDShop.Buffer.Started = true;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            if (true == true) // Do not mind this
            {
                services.AddHsts(ops =>
                {
                    ops.Preload = true;
                    ops.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                });

                services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
                {
                    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
                    options.HttpsPort = 443;
                });
            }

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            AR.Statistic.Visits.Initialize(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "Statistics"));
            AR.Statistic.Visitors.Initialize(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "Statistics"));

            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
                // app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently, 443));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                Program.AbsolutePath = env.WebRootPath;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `HstsOption` to include subdomains:

```cs
services.AddHsts(ops =>
{
    ops.IncludeSubDomains = true;
});
```

I assume you already have `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in startup, right?

Reference:

- [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#require-https)
- [HstsOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.httpspolicy.hstsoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 0):

> Just to add at Laz Ziya point the following code snippet should work ,
>   have used the same in one of my projects. Hope you have used
>   HttpsRedirection() method properly Check this out and the ports can be
>   mentionted in appsettings.json

---

> Blockquote

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Comment: References :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
Your HTTPS middleware is setup properly, but your web app itself might not be listening to `www.website.com`.
Configure your Web server ( IIS ,kestrel, apache or any other ) and (or) the DNS provider to resolve requests from `www.website.com`, `website.com` to your web application

**Long Story**

**HttpsRedirection middleware** (`app.UseHttpsRedirection()`) works irrespective of the URL being used to access your application.

> i.e. whether you use `http://website.com` or `http://abc.xyz.website.com:2312`, the middleware will redirect properly to `https://website.com:443` & `http://abc.xyz.website.com:443` respectively. ( assuming **HttpsPort** is set to 443)

**Reference** : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HttpsPolicy/src/HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.cs

```
        var port = _httpsPort.Value;
        if (port == PortNotFound)
        {
            return _next(context);
        }

        var host = context.Request.Host;
        if (port != 443)
        {
            host = new HostString(host.Host, port);
        }
        else
        {
            host = new HostString(host.Host);
        }

        var request = context.Request;
        var redirectUrl = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
            "https", 
            host,
            request.PathBase,
            request.Path,
            request.QueryString);
```

> In Nutshell, what the middleware does, is use the original URL which was used to access your application, and just change the original port to 443 (HttpsPort).

Now as to why you might be facing the issue, your application (or app server) itself might not be listening to requests from `http://www.website.com`.

If you are using kestrel, you can configure it to listen to all requests on port 80 and 443.

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:80"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:443"
      }
    }
  },
```

If you are testing on your local machine, then you have to add individual entries to the hosts file for all the subdomains your application is listening to (*www* in your case).
(Hosts file is located at `/etc/hosts` in linux & `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` in windows)
e.g.

```
#various other entries.
127.0.0.1 www.website.com
127.0.0.1 website.com
```

In a production environment, you will have to configure the DNS provider to resolve both `www.website.com` && `website.com` to the IP address where your app is hosted.

**Some other useful links** 
[How to set up subdomains on IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069278/how-to-set-up-subdomains-on-iis-7)

https://superuser.com/questions/449392/multiple-subdomains-pointing-to-one-website-in-iis

Comment: Did you really try checking your webserver if it is listening to request on www subdomain?
The fact that your website is not working when requested on http://www.website.com or www.website.com is a prime indicator of it.
To be completely sure, Insert a dummy middleware at the very start of your pipeline, put a breakpoint and check it is hit when you send a request from www.website.com. If you don't receive any, then it is not your code's fault, but rather your server configuration 
e.g. https://imgur.com/KoLhLQX

Comment: I found out solution but it is not related to this problem. Looks like everything works fine but my certificate was problem. Since i have certificate for my website (site.com) that same certificate is not working on `www.site.com` so what i did is purchase another certificate and it is working now.